# Rails module self.table_name_prefix is not working on production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this code:

```
# app/models/ta.rb

module Ta
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'ta_'
  end
end
```

...

```
# app/models/ta/article.rb

module Ta
  class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
end
```

From the rails console...

```
# development environment

Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.6)
2.1.3 :001 > Ta::Article.table_name
 => "ta_articles" 
2.1.3 :002 >
```

...

```
# production environment

Loading production environment (Rails 4.1.6)
2.1.3 :001 > Ta::Article.table_name
 => "articles" 
2.1.3 :002 >
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you checked to see that your prod environment is requiring the module correctly? If not, try requiring explicitly and see if that changes the behavior.

Comment: You are right, thanks! requiring the module manually works! now the question is, why rails is not requiring modules automatically?

Comment: A couple of things I would check is 1) any autoloading you're performing, 2) seeing if having a module that's not an AR class as a 'spearhead' namespace trips up Rails, or (shudders) bust out the [requiring guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#automatic-modules) if you really want it to work automatically. In my experience, if I really need a specific layout I'm better off requiring manually than relying on Rails autoloader.

Answer (score 3):

Add to `config/initializers/namespace.rb` something like:

```
require Rails.root.join('app', 'models', 'ta')
```

should solve your problem.